# Create list of lambda functions dynamically where each next function uses the previous function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create list of `lambdas` by a given size *n* (so manual assignment won't work) where each element depends on **previous** function and it index in the list.

I've tried various stuff like this :

```py
n = 3
func_list = [lambda x : 1]
for k in range(1,n):
    func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[k-1](x) * (x+k))
print(list(map(lambda f : print(f(1)), func_list)))
```

But in all attempts I've got error message about `recursion` depth:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-296-f35123a830c4> in <module>
      2 for k in range(1,3):
      3     func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[k-1](x) * (x+k))
----> 4 print(list(map(lambda f : print(f(1)), func_list)))

<ipython-input-296-f35123a830c4> in <lambda>(f)
      2 for k in range(1,3):
      3     func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[k-1](x) * (x+k))
----> 4 print(list(map(lambda f : print(f(1)), func_list)))

<ipython-input-296-f35123a830c4> in <lambda>(x)
      1 func_list = [lambda x : 1]
      2 for k in range(1,3):
----> 3     func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[k-1](x) * (x+k))
      4 print(list(map(lambda f : print(f(1)), func_list)))

 ... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-296-f35123a830c4> in <lambda>(x)
      1 func_list = [lambda x : 1]
      2 for k in range(1,3):
----> 3     func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[k-1](x) * (x+k))
      4 print(list(map(lambda f : print(f(1)), func_list)))

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: What kind of function you are expecting from the lambdas? Since in the for loop you are actually executing the lambda function. See here`func_list[k-1](x)`

Comment: Also, you might want to spend some time on the `late binding` of closures (lambdas): e.g. [read this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Comment: You had this behavior because because all method use the same `reference K`, and `k == 2`, so every `k - 1` will return the same result in all method so you keep returning the same element until you got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Elegant Odoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845873/4909228) pointed out, Python lambdas capture variables by *reference*.

Another term that you might hear when searching for answers is "**late binding**", which means binding of the variable inside the lambda to its actual value happens only when the lambda is executed. As a results, all lambda functions you've created has the same (and final) value for `k`, which causes infinite recursion.

While the `exec`-based approach is valid, I think most people would agree that `exec` should be avoided in practical code. An alternative solution to this is to create lambda functions via functions to force early binding:

```
n = 3
func_list = [lambda x: 1]

def create_fn(k_val):
    return lambda x: func_list[k_val - 1](x) * (x + k_val)

for k in range(1, n):
    func_list.append(create_fn(k))

print(list(map(lambda f: f(1), func_list)))
```

When you call `create_fn` with `k`, the current value of `k` is passed to the function under the name `k_val`. The variable `k_val` in the lambda function is then bound to the `k_val` variable in the scope of `create_fn`, with the value of `k` at the time when it's called.

Comment: "by reference" is really not standard terminology here. Python uses lexically scoped, late-binding closures.

Comment: I agree, which is why I used "late binding" in the explanation. However, I do believe that "reference vs. value" is a common topic in programming languages, and it might  help to at least use it as an analogy.

Answer (score 1):

A very good case to explain the difference between Reference and Value:

Let me explain why this happen to understand what happen lets use
a normal function so we can debug the value of K:

```py
    n = 3
    func_list = [lambda x : 1]
    for k in range(1,n):
        def f(x):
            print('K is: ', k)
            return func_list[k-1](x) * (x + k)
        func_list.append(f)

    # just print will be enough to cause error
    print(func_list[2])
```

Out puts is:

```
    K is : 2
    K is : 2
    K is : 2
    K is : 2
    K is : 2
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

You are using the same variable (**reference to value**) in all methods. K reference to value 2 generated from the loop.

to demonstrate after the end of loop make `k = 5`, this will raise error `index out of range`.

A simple solution with `exec` :

```py
    n = 3
    func_list = [lambda x: 1]
    for k in range(1, n):
        # here you are not using variable k we are using the value it's like
        # we are rewriting it to code every time but is not you who typing it's the compute -_^
        exec('func_list.append(lambda x : func_list[{k}-1](x) * (x + {k}))'.format(k=k))

    # lambda print(f(1)) will create [None, None, None] I removed the print
    print(list(map(lambda f: f(1), func_list)))
```

Out put:

```
    [1, 2, 6]
```

Of curse the solution above work for your case because `K` is jut a simple `Integer`
what if `K` is an **very complicated object**, with **complicated attributes** and **private
variable**. In order to achieve the same thing you need to reconstruct the object.

```
    # we need to consract another object using the value
    exec('... KClass({}, {}, {}) ...'.format(k.attr1, k.attr2, k.attr2))
```

Imaging that `KClass` uses attribute Object of `XClass` you will need to construct both object `k and x`.

SO using `exec` is not practical a better way to handle this is the Factory Pattern:

```py
    n = 3
    func_list = [lambda x: 1]


    def method_factory(k):
        # here K reference it's not the same K reference that is created
        # in loop there are different but with the alias K
        return lambda x: func_list[k - 1](x) * (x + k)


    for k in range(1, n):
        func_list.append(method_factory(k))

    print(list(map(lambda f: f(1), func_list)))
```

Why this work because when you call `method_factory` this will create its own **scope** that contain
a **reference** with alias `K` that ***point*** to the same `value` that reference `K` of `loop` points to.

Hope you got the idea it's all about `reference` and `scopes`.